# Display more data from a lookup column in sharepoint

Tags: xml, sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I am using Sharepoint 2007 and have a list `Order` that has a lookup column from list `Item` and displays `Item Name`. Order accepts multiple `Item` values.

On my page that displays an `Order`, how do I iterate over each `Item` and  display other fields like `Item ID` and `Item Price`?

In Sharepoint Designer 2007 I have converted the webpart to xslt data view. Using `@Item` just displays each `Item Name` as a single string separated by a semi colon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible OOTB in SP2007 as the Joins Property was not added to SPQuery until SharePoint 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.joins%28v=office.14%29.aspx

A common workaround though is to use some event handler or SPD workflow (it would need to automatically run on insert & edit) to concatenate the values you want into a separate field. Perhaps you call it "Items for Lookup" and in your code or workflow, you concatenate it as ItemID: Item Name - Item Price

This way, your data is 'pre-concatenated', so to speak. Not the prettiest approach but working in SharePoint rarely is ;)